# Adding text to a drawable shape

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, android-drawable

I have this drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
<shape>
  <solid
      android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
</shape>
</item>

<item>
<shape>
  <gradient
      android:startColor="#8FED85"
      android:endColor="#4CD43D"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

And it is shown by using this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:enterFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime">


<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_focused="true"   android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector"/>


 </selector>
```

And here is the listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
    android:divider="#fff"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:dividerHeight="0.9dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector_animation"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:background="#fff"
    >

</ListView>
```

The drawable is a green "box" that shows up in a listview when an item inside the list is selected, what i would like to do is to also show a text inside the drawable like "tap again to send" or something like that, any tips on how i could add the text inside the drawable shape?

Comment: if you want to add static/dynamic text to some drawable you can extend Drawable class and override its draw method

Comment: you can put this drawable onto a button, as its background, and use its setText to add the text

Answer (score 1):

you can put this drawable onto a button, as its background, and use its setText to add the text